# Transparent image on transparent image PHP

Tags: php, image, transparent

I'll explain a bit of my situation.

We got an island with cities. These could be:

- Owned by my alliance
- Owned by an enemy
- Owned by nobody (free)

So we got 3 "cities"-images and an island image, looks like this:

[image: Island]

[image: No owner]

[image: Alliance]

[image: Enemy]

Now we want to put these cities images on the island image. For example, we put a city owned by nobody on the island like this:

```
<?php
// Get image
$im = imagecreatefrompng('island.png');
imagealphablending($im,true);

// Get our "Free-city-position" image
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('free.png');

$pos_x = 190 - 15; // Position X = 190 - the half of the free.png image = 30 / 2 = 15
$pos_y = 225 - 15;// Position Y = 225 - the half of the free.png image = 30 / 2 = 15

imagealphablending($stamp,true);
imagecopy($im, $stamp, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output image
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

And now there is our problem: The city image is not transparent on the island image! It looks like this:
[image: Island with city]

I thought `imagealphablending` should do the trick, but unfortunately, it doesn't.

How can we get the transparant city image on the island?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from PHP's comment on GD functions :

> If you are trying to copy a transparant image on to another image, you
>   might assume that you should apply the ImageAlphaBlending function to
>   the image that has the transparancy, the source image. In reality, you
>   must apply the ImageAlphaBlending function to the destination image.
>   Basically it's saying, "make the specified image respect
>   transparancy".

Comment: That means I've to add the `imagealphablending` function above the `header(...)` to `$im`? Sadly, that is not working...

Comment: No, it means, only set imagealphablending to the background image and not the foreground image. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php - 2nd comment

Comment: But that is not the solution. When I change the image to a JPG (JPEG) image it works. Is there any solution for PNG images?

Comment: Maybe check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281395/merging-multiple-overlapping-transparent-png-images-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f
<?php
// Read island image and get dimensions
$island=imagecreatefrompng("island.png");
$w_island=imagesx($island);
$h_island=imagesy($island);

// Read city image and get dimensions
$city= imagecreatefrompng("city.png");
$w_city=imagesx($city);
$h_city=imagesy($city);

// Create output image
$result=imagecreatetruecolor($w_island,$h_island);
imagesavealpha($result,true);
$transparent=imagecolorallocatealpha($result, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($result, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Splat island onto transparent background
imagecopy($result, $island, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_island, $h_island);
// Splat city ontop
imagecopy($result, $city, 100, 280, 0, 0, $w_city, $h_city);
imagepng($result,"result.png");
?>
```

[image]