# Drop shadow on imagephp being turned black

Tags: php, gd, shadow

So I created a script from PHP Doc and some helpful threads/advice on SO and came out with this:

```
$filename = time();

$glassurl = $_GET['GlassImg'];
$frameurl = $_GET['FrameImg'];
$handleurl = "images/helpbutton.png";
$handleurl2 = "images/helpbutton.png";

$glassimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($glassurl);
$frameimg = imagecreatefromgif($frameurl);
$handleimg = imagecreatefrompng($handleurl);
$handleimg2 = imagecreatefrompng($handleurl2);

$frame_x = imagesx($frameimg);
$frame_y = imagesy($frameimg);
imagecopymerge($glassimg, $frameimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $frame_x, $frame_y, 100);

imagecolortransparent($handleimg, imagecolorat($handleimg, 0, 0));
imagecolortransparent($handleimg2, imagecolorat($handleimg2, 0, 0));

$handle_x = imagesx($handleimg);
$handle_y = imagesy($handleimg);
imagecopymerge($glassimg, $handleimg, 460, 150, 0, 0, $handle_x, $handle_y, 100);


$handle2_x = imagesx($handleimg2);
$handle2_y = imagesy($handleimg2);
imagecopymerge($glassimg, $handleimg2, 5, 5, 0, 0, $handle2_x, $handle2_y, 100);

// Output and free from memory
imagepng($glassimg, "uploads/$filename.png");

imagedestroy($glassimg);
imagedestroy($frameimg);
imagedestroy($handleimg);
imagedestroy($handleimg2);
```

It pretty much works perfectly, however there is a slight issue. The helpbutton.png which is just a placeholder image to see that i can position images and merge them ends up with a solid black drop shadow that causes the image to look horrible.

This is what it should look like:

[image: helpbutton.png]

This is how it comes out once merged:

[image: helpresult.png]

I have looked into a lot of the image controls including blending and such, but none seem to affect it. Does anyone know how to control that drop shadow shouldn't be darkened in PHP?

Comment: it might be because you are uploading the image which is not a png image try  uploading a png image

Comment: which image is not a png? both the help buttons and the final image produced are. You mean the gif and the jpeg?

Comment: Also you have not added the original images to your post. Adding those would better explain your input which might be part of your issue.

Comment: I think it has to do with the imagecopymerge, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355993/phpgd-imagecopymerge-not-retaining-png-transparencies

Comment: Tried using two pngs instead, had no affect. So resorted back to jpeg/gif. looking into hakres comment now.

Answer (score 0):

`imagesavealpha($res, true)` & `imagealphablending($res, false)` comes in handy, when you save png images with alpha channel (especially, when you opened from jpeg).

**Edit**: try this:

```
$glassimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($glassurl);
imagealphablending($glassimg, false);
imagesavealpha($glassimg, true)

$frameimg = imagecreatefromgif($frameurl);
imagealphablending($frameimg, false);
imagesavealpha($frameimg, true)

$handleimg = imagecreatefrompng($handleurl);
imagealphablending($handleimg, false);
imagesavealpha($handleimg, true)

$handleimg2 = imagecreatefrompng($handleurl2);
imagealphablending($handleimg2, false);
imagesavealpha($handleimg2, true)
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it made no difference... thank you though :)

Comment: did you applied on every image resource (just after opened) which are in `imagecopy` / `imagecopymerge` arguments, too?

Comment: I have tried this.. and unfortunately it still has a black drop shadow :/ seems to have no effect at all for some reason. thank you very much for the edit though.

Comment: Then, it will be you image files - i think. You should use images already with alpha channels saved, not manually set with `imagecolortransparent`.

Comment: But as I understand it, jpegs are the only image type that don't have alpha channels. I used a png instead of a jpeg, and the same issue occurs. And seeing as im saving the alpha setting (theoretically) it should work?

Comment: Yes, its not enough to convert it to png, when you save it with alpha channel, you'll see, these dots (that not transparent in your example) is not exactly the same color, you set to be the transparent color in php.